# How do I upload animated gifs from Twitter onto Facebook and have them animate?

Tags: facebook, twitter

Animated GIFS [on Twitter](http://techcrunch.com/2015/06/16/twitter-now-autoplays-video-and-gifs/) are great for capturing a meme. Downloading them is tricky, but can be done by reading the HTML source or using an external tool.

The problem I have is, whenever I upload an animated gif to Facebook, it fails to animate, only showing the first frame.

My question is: How do I upload animated gifs from Twitter onto Facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter generates an mp4 for an animated GIF, so you can upload it as a video to Facebook.

e.g. via the API

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show.json?id=479307198901026816

```
      "variants": [
        {
          "bitrate": 0,
          "content_type": "video/mp4",
          "url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/tweet_video/BqbXWaHIYAEciGo.mp4"
        }
```

So you can upload this

Comment: Thanks Yuri - always good to see a UTS'er from the 90's on here.

Comment: "Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them."

Answer (score 0):

You don't, gifs in albums wall posts will be converted to JPG stills by facebooks CDN.

Link to the image and it will animate as expected. If you paste the link and wait a few seconds before hitting the post button it will embed the image as part of your post.

Answer (score 0):

You can't natively, but you can use a third-party service such as [Giphy](http://giphy.com) to upload GIFs, then have it convert that gif into an HTML5 video you can embed. This should then animate automatically when you post to Facebook.

To see this in action, select an existing gif from the site, then click the "Advanced" tab beneath it. You'll find a HTML5 video share link. Within the source is an MP4 file, which you can get by right clicking the video in your browser, then clicking "View Video" (in FireFox). You could then save the raw MP4 and upload it to your feed, if sharing the provided link does not have the desired effect.